# Where can I find a list of students expelled from university in Nazi Germany?

Tags: nazi-germany

I'm looking for a place to research the names of students expelled from university in Nazi Germany, from 1933 to 1936.

The reasons for expulsion would be being under suspicion of some anti-Nazi criterion: communist, possible foreign spy, racial, etc.

Where can I start my research? Are there any sources in English about this topic? Thank you all.

Comment: Not saying it doesn't exist, but this sounds like something you may need to compile yourself if you are interested.

Comment: I would imagine that many of the university records were destroyed/lost during the war, so any list you might be able to compile is likely to be incomplete.

Comment: That sounds like a pretty long list, especially if you want to sort people out who were expelled for specific reasons. I would also be curious how reliable such a list can be if it exists. There are several subtle and less subtle ways to get rid of someone without going over all the bureaucratic steps of expelling.